It is possible to create trigger on event equal to start-session (basic GA4 event)?
I need to create a trigger that fires when a session starts (it should be the same as the GA4 "session_start" event) to create a tag for Google Ads (Google Ads conversion tracking).
This is required to create a web conversion with a non-GA4 attribution window, and actually the session_start event from GA4 works for me.
I tried creating a custom event with the event name "session_start" but it didn't work.
